# Parse S3FileAdapter

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-s3, parse-server

I currently have a parse-server deployment working however every time I upload a file it stores it with the `GridStore` file adapter instead of the S3 one. My app JS looks like this:

```
// Example express application adding the parse-server module to expose Parse
// compatible API routes.

var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'somAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  },
  filesAdapter: new S3Adapter(
    "S31",
    "S32",
    "bucket-name",
    {directAccess: true}
  )
});
// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var app = express();

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('Make sure to star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
});

// There will be a test page available on the /test path of your server url
// Remove this before launching your app
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

After I deploy I do not get any errors. Everything seems to be running fine. However, when I upload a file it goes to my monglab DB instead of my S3 storage. Do I need to do something else to configure this? I'm using the docs as a reference to configure this:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Configuring-File-Adapters

I also noticed that on the parse-server repo it does not have an S3FileAdapter:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/tree/master/src/Adapters/Files

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

David

Comment: Hi David, I'm having same exact issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

mLab db do not store files. It only stores the link of file. You need to upload files to S3 first. If successful, Parse server will return a filename, then, write the name to the db. I use curl command to check file-writing. If it works, your settings should be okay.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: YOUR-APP-ID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: YOUR-KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
  -d 'Hello, it is me!' \
  http://your-parse-server/parse/files/filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this script and it's work fine

```
filesAdapter: new S3Adapter(
    "ACCESS_KEY",
    "SECRET_KEY",
    "BUCKET_NAME",
    "REGION"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing the exact same problem, when gone through in `parse-server/lib/Adapters/AdapterLoader.js`, I found `filesAdapter` allowed custom module with configuration options or function. So I tried with below solution which works fine for me.

```
var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;
var api = new ParseServer({
...
filesAdapter: () => {
    return new S3Adapter("ACCESS_KEY", "SECRET_KEY", "BUCKET_NAME")  
}
...
});
```